# How to apply UV map texture while keeping node shaders?

Tags: node-editor

How would I apply the UV map texture I have here to the object (in place of what's currently the colour) whilst still keeping my diffuse and glossy shader?

[image]

Comment: This question is so fundamental to texturing. You have obviously not even taken the time to read the documentation. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/image.html

Answer (score 0):

You would add a texture (image texture) node, and wire the color output of the image texture node into the color input on the diffuse node only. And leave the glossy color white.